# Managing one-to-many relations / cant get any relations?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've problem with managing my relations (just in mysql, lol! ;))

**MySQL Scheme:**

One property can have multiple values. For example:
Property id 1 => Value id 1, Value id 4
Property id 2 => Value id 1, Value id 3, Value id 2

**sql:**

```
CREATE TABLE `property_values` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `value_img` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `property_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_44D0239A549213EC` (`property_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_44D0239A549213EC` FOREIGN KEY (`property_id`) REFERENCES `property` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `property` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4        COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**What i've done?**

```
php bin/console make:entity
```

and created realations in user entity OneToMany:
**Property.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\PropertyValues", mappedBy="property")
 */
private $propertyValue;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->propertyValue = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @return Collection|PropertyValues[]
 */
public function getPropertyValue(): Collection
{
    return $this->propertyValue;
}
```

and in **PropertyValues.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Property", inversedBy="propertyValue")
 */
private $property;

public function getProperty(): ?Property
{
    return $this->property;
}

public function setProperty(?Property $property): self
{
    $this->property = $property;

    return $this;
}
```

in **my Controller** file, i need to create table, so i doing this:

```
    $property = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Property::class)
        ->find($id);

    if (!$property) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            '404:' . $id;
        );
    }

    return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'HomeController',
        'property' => $property
    ]);
```

but when im trying to dump property var in my twig template by:

```
{{dump(property}}
```

i got property data but without any elements from PropertyElements:

```
-propertyValue: PersistentCollection^ {#834 ▼
-snapshot: []
-owner: Property^ {#770}
-association: array:15 [ …15]
-em: EntityManager^ {#522 …11}
-backRefFieldName: "property"
-typeClass: ClassMetadata {#772 …}
-isDirty: false
#collection: ArrayCollection^ {#741 ▼
  -elements: []
}
```

**property_values table info:**

```
KEY `IDX_44D0239A549213EC` (`property_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_44D0239A549213EC` FOREIGN KEY (`property_id`)
REFERENCES `property` (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

It is my first touch with ORM. Im trying to do this from a few hours. In mysql i simply use "JOIN" query and everything worked :)

How can i select all of data from Property joining PropertyValues?

I appreciate your help with this!

**schema:validate**:

```
Mapping
-------                                                                                           
[OK] The mapping files are correct.                                                                                                                                                           
Database
-------
[OK] The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.                                    

[OK] Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.
```

Comment: Could you please take a look at [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information) and add to your question the output of these commands :
- bin/console doctrine:schema:validate
- bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

Comment: Maybe you forgot to populate the database with the right values?

Comment: Checked it 10 times :( - propertyValues.property_id defined the same like proprety.id